# IONIC Framework - how to detect simultaneous tap gesture with two fingers in Android?

Tags: android, gesture, ionic-framework

I am using Yo Ionic for building my android app. I have two 3 div.row where I want to detect onTap and onRelease gestures on both the DIVs, irrespective of their timing. Currently, When I tap and hold on one div, the other div doesn't respond! Vice versa on the oposite side. ANy pointers?

Comment: having the same issue, see my duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903877/how-to-enable-ionic-multi-touch-events

Comment: try using 'touchstart' and 'touchend' event instead of tap events that may works..